# Play 2.1-Snapshot: Ebean database updates and deletions don't work in Junit test cases

Tags: java, orm, playframework, junit4, ebean

I have a weird problem. I'm using play 2.1-SNAPSHOT with ebeans (=> mysql). I have a very small (test) setup and for some reason database updates and deletions don't work. Items are created in the DB... but updating them does not work.

Here's my bean (which extends a superclass that adds the timestamps (created and modified date)):

AbstractTimestamp (superclass):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractTimestampedBean extends AbstractIdentifiableBean {
    /** The date this item has been created. */
    @CreatedTimestamp
    public Timestamp createdTime;
}
```

Project Bean (removed unimportant stuff) - hashCode and equals have been created by eclipse - here we overwrite the methods of play.db.ebean.Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Projects")
public class Project extends AbstractTimestampedBean {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6160140283947231026L;

    @NotNull
    public String title;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public User owner;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public User creator;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<User> participants;

    @EnumMapping(nameValuePairs = "ACTIVE=A,INACTIVE=I,EXPIRED=E")
    public enum Status {
        ACTIVE, INACTIVE, EXPIRED
    }

    public Project() {
    }

    public Project(final String title, final User creator) {
        this.title = title;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.owner = creator;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see play.db.ebean.Model#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result
                        + (this.creator == null ? 0 : this.creator.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                        + (this.owner == null ? 0 : this.owner.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                        + (this.participants == null ? 0 : this.participants
                                        .hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                        + (this.title == null ? 0 : this.title.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see play.db.ebean.Model#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Project other = (Project) obj;
        if (this.creator == null) {
            if (other.creator != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.creator.equals(other.creator)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.owner == null) {
            if (other.owner != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.owner.equals(other.owner)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.participants == null) {
            if (other.participants != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.participants.equals(other.participants)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.title == null) {
            if (other.title != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.title.equals(other.title)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here's the very simple test case:

First run creates a projects - checks that it's there (nothing fails here)

Then we update some stuff - store it - and assert again... and here I can see that the db entries have not been updated.

http://pastebin.com/7zdzWGXw

Here's the superclass that we are using here:

```
public abstract class AbstractPersistableTestCase {
    @Transactional
    void saveBean(final Model bean) {
        Ebean.save(bean);
    }

    @Transactional
    void deleteBean(final Model bean) {
        Ebean.delete(bean);
    }

    @Transactional
    <T extends Model> void deleteBeans(final List<T> beans) {
        Ebean.delete(beans);
    }
}
```

Error message from jUnit4:

This is the assertion of the title in the update case => See: db entry has not been updated:

```
[error] Test test.models.ProjectTest.createAndUpdateProject failed: expected:<'Project_[NEW_]1350681993608'> but was:<Project_[]1350681993608'>
```

This happens when I try to delete the project:

```
[error] Test test.models.ProjectTest.deleteProjects failed: Data has changed. updated [0] rows sql[delete from user where id=? and name is null and email is null and created_time is null] bind[null]
```

Do you guys have an idea why this is happening? I'm really frustrated here...

Regards,

Sascha

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not adding an Id to your classes.

Try to add this to your superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractModel extends play.db.ebean.Model
{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    // ... here your other attributes
}
```